# RAMDisk reliability

Tags: build-process, ramdisk

I was looking at the existing RAMDisk discussions ... and none seem to bring up any reliability issues. I recently started using a Dataram ramdisk for my source code and am wondering if there are any risks I should be concerned with.

It did speed up the compile time by 30%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not fully familiar with that product, but the answer probably depends on whether you have a (good) UPS, and what you are using to sync changes with your hard drive. I had looked into this a while ago (on a linux machine) mapping a portion of the ram as a disk and using RSYNC to persist changes to the hard drive, but discontinued the idea and got a faster hard drive instead :) I would be very interested in seeing this working...

Comment: that particular ramdisk software provides a autosave to disk image option. And no UPS to speak off right now ...